# How to convert english to spanish language in an application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslocalizedstring

I am having a table view. In that two rows are there ,1st row name **English** and 2nd row name **Spanish**.

When i select the 1st row my whole app change to **English Language**,
and select the 2nd row my app change to **Spanish Language**. How to do this?

I am new to this concept.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get some refrence from below URL:

[Change Language within App](https://github.com/mumensh/iOS-Localization/blob/master/Language%20Class/Language.h)

I have used same.